Difference between the infinitesimal elements of hemispherical shell and solid hemisphere
Question:
While calculating the center of mass of a uniform solid hemisphere, we consider the differential element:
$$\mathrm{d}m = \rho \pi r^2 R \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \cos\theta$$
where $r = R \cos \theta$, $\rho$ is the mass density, and $\theta$ is the angle with the horizontal. Here, we take
$$R \, \mathrm{d}\theta \cos\theta$$
as the width of the disk (which we’re using to build up the solid hemisphere). However, when calculating the center of mass for a hemispherical shell, we take the differential element as:
$$\mathrm{d}m = \rho_s \cdot 2 \pi r \cdot R \, \mathrm{d}\theta$$
where
$r = R \cos \theta$ and $\rho_s$ is the surface mass density. This time we don't take $R \, \mathrm{d}\theta \cos\theta$, just $R \, \mathrm{d}\theta$.
My question is:
Why do we include
$$R \, \mathrm{d}\theta \cos \theta$$
in the case of the solid hemisphere. Why can't I write this the same way as I did in the hollow hemisphere.
I don't understand why we have to take the vertical height in the case of solid hemisphere. Why don't we consider the tangential height to calculate the volume.
What is the fundamental difference that causes us to consider the two cases separately. Why is one different from the other?
If I take the tangential slant height for calculating the volume, why would my answer be wrong?
The question that's assumed to be answering my problem isn't actually answering it because for me, the problem is with the solid hemispherical shell and not the hollow hemispherical shell.


This question is similar to: Discrepancy in center of mass of a uniform hemispherical shell of zero thickness. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The diagram already clearly answers your question, no? Can you clarify why you think $\cos\theta$ should be included for the hemispherical shell?

For the solid hemisphere each element is a slice of thickness $R \cos \theta d \theta$ and cross-sectional area $\pi r^2 = \pi R^2 \cos^2 \theta$, so its mass is
$dm = \rho \pi r^2 R \cos \theta d \theta = \rho \pi R^3 \cos^3 \theta d \theta$
For the hemispherical shell each element is a two-dimensional ring with radius $r = R \cos \theta$ and width $R d\theta$ - here we are interested in the width of the ring along the tangent to the hemisphere, not its vertical thickness. So the mass of this element is
$dm = \rho (2 \pi r) R d \theta = 2 \rho \pi R^2 \cos \theta d \theta$

"here we are interested in the width of the ring along the tangent to the hemisphere, not its vertical thickness."
Can you please explain this part.

@AnantTyagi For the hemispherical shell - which has zero thickness - all of the material lies on the surface of the hemisphere, so the area of an elemental ring is calculated by multiplying its circumference $2 \pi r$ (which we assume to be constant since $d \theta$ is small) by its width on the surface of the hemisphere, which is $R d \theta$.

Okay, but then why can't I multiply the area of the disks by $Rd\theta$. I understand that taking their vertical height makes more sense, but I would really appreciate if you can explain the fundamental differences. Is there something that's got to do with the adding of the volumes, vs the adding of the areas. And if there is can someone explain it with a little bit of mathematics involved.

@AnantTyagi If you use the slant height $R d \theta$ as the slice thickness in the solid hemisphere then you are over-estimating the slice thickness when $\theta$ is close to $90$ degrees (because you have dropped the factor $\cos \theta$).

I got a little confused about how it's different that we calculate area over a surface from how we calculate the volume. Also, the terminology of the words, "thickness", and "width" added to that confusion. But I think I've got it now. Thank you.
